# storing int32 in a byte array

Tags: c#

How can I store an int32 at a specific location in a byte array?

As far as I can tell, I need to use BitConverter.GetBytes(value); to get the byte[4].

Then I have a byte[whatever_size] and offset.

```
public void SetInt32(byte[] message, int offset, Int32 value)
{
var value_bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
message[offset] = value_bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the bytes directly by using bitwise arithmetic:

```
byte temp[4];
temp[3] = value & 0xFF;
temp[2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
temp[1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
temp[0] = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    message[offset+i] = temp[i];
```

Comment: i can't assign a short to a byte

Comment: @Bluebaron: cast it like this `(byte)((value >> 24) & 0xFF)`

Comment: This is the Big-Endian representation, if you're transferring these bytes to another function (or machine) you'll need to be aware of how the recipient expects the byte order to be.

Comment: @Bluebaron: It's an explicit cast, and yes, it is safe, since all unimportant bits are already either shifted out or set to 0 anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `BitConverter` and then `Buffer.BlockCopy` or `Array.Copy` to copy the contents of the "new" byte array into the other one.

Alternatively, you could take the `EndianBitConverter` code from [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) which not only allows you to specify the endianness, but also allows you to avoid creating the redundant array:

```
EndianBitConverter.Little.CopyBytes(value, message, offset);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
value_bytes.CopyTo(message, offset);
```

instead of

```
message[offset] = value_bytes;
```

assuming that `message` is you other byte array and `offset` is an int specifying the location at which to copy.